# "Identifier required" Error Accessing an Array Element

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I was trying to place all the rows of the Column "Title" of the dataset into the string array. But i get an error Identifier Required at strdeals[] in the last line. where am i doing wrong?

```
string[] strdeals = new string[100];

Dataset dsdeal;
for(int i =0; i< dsdeal.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{

 strdeals[] =  dsdeal.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Title"].Tostring();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't subscripted the `strdeals` array. Try this:

```
strdeals[i] = dsdeal.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Title"].ToString();
```

Comment: Oh Ok. I got you. Thanks Andrew :)